# Generating a Unique, Sequential ID in Excel According to the String Value in Another Column

Tags: excel, vba

In Column A of my excel sheet I'm trying to create a unique, sequential ID in each row according to the 'activity type' in Column C. `Activity Title` is in Column B, but the two relevant columns for this example are Column A and Column C. There are three activity types: `Milestones`, `Tasks`, and `Subtasks`.

It might seem straight forward, but just to make sure I've provided all relevant details, a 'Milestone' is like an agile epic - it's the largest body of work and can have several tasks and subtasks aligned to it. A 'Task' is like an agile feature - one 'Task' can have several subtasks aligned to it. And finally, a 'Subtask' is like an agile user story - It is the smallest body of work and will not have anything aligned to it (or beneath it).

There is also no limit or pattern to the number of 'Tasks' that fall beneath one milestone, and no limit or pattern to the number of 'Subtasks' that fall beneath one 'Task. Ideally, I'd like the ID to be auto-generated in the following format:

| ID (ColA) | Activity Type (Col C) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Milestone |
| 1.1 | Task |
| 1.2 | Task |
| 1.21 | Subtask |
| 1.22 | Subtask |
| 1.3 | Task |
| 1.31 | Subtask |
| 2 | Milestone |
| 2.1 | Task |
| 2.11 | Subtask |
| 2.12 | Subtask |
| 2.13 | Subtask |
| 2.2 | Task |
| 2.21 | Subtask |

I should mention that I already have some code in VBA to auto indent the data in Column B (Activity Name) and Column C (Activity Type) according to the activity type. That code is included below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
 
If Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        If Target = "Task" Then
            Target.IndentLevel = 1
            Target.Offset(0, -1).IndentLevel = 1
        ElseIf Target = "Subtask" Then
            Target.IndentLevel = 2
            Target.Offset(0, -1).IndentLevel = 2
        End If

ErrHandler:
End Sub
```

Any and all help you can provide would be SO appreciated -- thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't the `2.22` and `1.23` be `2.12` and `2.13`? Typos in your question?

Comment: Is Column C actually listed as Milestone, Task, Subtask? Or are these actual names of the tasks and so on? Trying to understand what type of information is here and whether we can use it to create the IDs. Right now, I think we can use some math like IF ColC = "Milestone", x + 1, if ColC = "Task", x + .1, etc.

Comment: formula: Put in A2 and copy down: `=IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(A1+1/10^(MATCH(B2,{"Milestone","Task","Subtask"},0)-1),(MATCH(B2,{"Milestone","Task","Subtask"},0)-1)),1)`

Comment: BTW, if there are no limits to the number of tasks or subtasks, what happens when the number of tasks or subtasks exceeds 9?

Comment: @BigBen - yes it should, good catch! I made an update above to reflect that.

Comment: @MarkS. Column C has data validation in it to only allow 'Milestone', 'Task', 'Subtask'

Comment: @ScottCraner, hmm great question. There shouldn't be a scenario where there are 10 subtasks, but I guess hypothetically, there could be a situation where there are more than 10 tasks, which leaves me stumped on how to approach this now

Comment: most of the time for things like this the column is formatted as text and one uses `.` to denote a level change: `1.2.3` first milestone, second task, third subtask.  Then it does not matter how many tasks or subtasks.  And it becomes easier to parse later.

Comment: @ScottCraner, that's helpful context and makes total sense to me. So does the formula you posted above account for that update? The Answer provided below, as you noted too, is so close but doesn't work when there are column headers (which there are), and then I guess also wouldn't account for the change you've suggested here

Comment: no, neither formula will do the new format.  To fix the formula below wrap in IFERROR():  `=IFERROR(IF(C3="Milestone",FLOOR(A2,1)+1,IF(C3="Task",FLOOR(A2,0.1)+0.1,A2+0.01)),1)`

Comment: Unfortunately that's still making the first 'Milestone' in row 2 default to zero instead of 1

Comment: @WynPonder the first milestone number shouldnt be a formula, just manually start it at 1. Every row *after* that row should be the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an excel formula to achieve this interaction. It reads the number above it, and the activity type in its row and decides what its number should be.

`=IFERROR(IF(C3="Milestone",FLOOR(A2,1)+1,IF(C3="Task",FLOOR(A2,0.1)+0.1,A2+0.01)),1)`

Put the formula into the third row and drag it down.

In response to the discussion above about formats using 1.1.1 style, here is a formula that can automatically generate those numbers:

`=IF(C3="Milestone", (LEFT(A2, FIND(".",A2)-1)+1 )&".0.0", IF(C3="Task", LEFT(A2, FIND(".",A2))&(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,FIND(".",A2,FIND(".",A2)+1)-FIND(".",A2) )+1)&".0", LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2, FIND(".",A2)+1))&(RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2)- FIND(".",A2, FIND(".",A2)+1))+1)))`

The formula uses Left and Find to split the text based on the "." and iterates or resets it based on the Activity Type. Set the first Milestone ID to "1.0.0" and put this formula in the rows below that.

I tried to come up with a formula that would have Milestones as "1, 2, 3" instead of "1.0.0, 2.0.0, 3.0.0" but doing so would make Left and Find return blank strings and including If statements and IFERROR statements to handle possible blanks would multiply the size of the formula by triple. It was unsatisfactory to myself.

Comment: I get an error in A2 when using this formula if there are titles in A1.`FLOOR(A1,1)` will return an error if A1 is text.

Comment: True, I forgot to adjust it to account for headers.

Comment: For context, Row 1 is a header and row 2 is the first milestone @Toddleson

Comment: @WynPonder Yes this should work with row 1 headers.

Comment: Fantastic! Saw your comment above about starting after the first milestone and it works! To @ScottCraner's point though, is there a way to adjust this so that it would reflect milestones having a second decimal point to account for 10+ tasks and subtasks (For example 1.11.12)? Because now, if there are more than 10 tasks, it defaults to the next integer, which would imply a new milestone (i.e. the task after 1.9 default to 2)

Comment: @WynPonder that is a new question beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @WynPonder It interests me and I enjoy this type of puzzle, I'll see if i can come up with an excel formula that works that way.

Comment: Awesome, you're a lifesaver! Happy to post this to a new question if that would best

Comment: @Toddleson, I saw your update to the answer and it works! But to throw one more wrench in everything, should the subtasks default to .01 first? Reason I'm asking is because upon first glance, 1.1.1 is numerically the same as 1.1.10 (even though we know it's separate and distinct)

Comment: @WynPonder Change `(RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2)- FIND(".",A2, FIND(".",A2)+1))+1)`  to `TEXT(RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2)- FIND(".",A2, FIND(".",A2)+1))+1,"00")`